# How to change the default prior distribution in CARBayes package?

Tags: bayesian

CARBayes version 5.0 implements spatial generalized linear models in R, with inference in a Bayesian setting using MCMC simulation. It contains a number of different models, the one this question is in reference to is ‘S.CARbym’.

I am using this model to fit a Poisson GLM with spatial random effects, a sample code is given in the first block below where ‘Y’ is the response, ‘x1’ ‘x2’ ‘x3’ are covariates, and ‘N’ is the offset. This formula is used in S.CARbym (model1), specifying a Poisson distribution and a known spatial weights matrix ‘W’.

This seems to work well, however I am unsure how to specify prior distributions for ‘prior.mean.beta’ and ‘prior.var.beta’ which are different from the default (the default priors are Gaussian and not included in the first block of code below). I am wondering what code I would need to input after ‘prior.mean.beta=’ (instead of ‘NULL’) in the second block of code below for model2 in order to specify a different prior distribution, for example Gamma or uniform?

The accompanying vignette to this package is helpful but I have been unable to figure this out, any help would be appreciated.

formula <- Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + offset(log(N))
model1 <- S.CARbym(formula = formula, family = poisson, data = data, W=W, burnin = 5000, n.sample = 20000, thin = 10)

formula <- Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + offset(log(N))
model2 <- S.CARbym(formula = formula, family = poisson, data = data, W=W, burnin = 5000, n.sample = 20000, thin = 10, prior.mean.beta=NULL, prior.var.beta=NULL)

Answer (score 0):

I have since resolved this issue with the expert help of Duncan Lee (package author). So, I thought I would answer in case anyone else is facing this problem. 
It was actually a much simpler solution than I thought, each single regression parameter needs a Gaussian prior, i.e. beta_j ~ N(m_j, v_j). (m_j, v_j) can be chosen by you and be different for each regression parameter, so if you wish to specify the prior means and variances they each need to be a vector of the number of regression parameters. E.g. if you had 3 regression parameters and an intercept the vector would need to by 4 by 1, something like the following m <- c(0,0,0,0)